# VirtualBox guest running OSX Mountain Lion: XCode install error

Tags: xcode, driver, virtualbox, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to install Xcode in a VirtualBox Hackintosh for app development purposes. I used MultiBeast and the Xcode installation is complaining about the display, but the way VirtualBox handles displays and graphics is beyond me.

I get the following error: `Xcode: CVCGDisplayLink::setCurrentDisplay didn't find a valid display -- falling back to 60Hz`.

I've currently followed the installation instructions from this [link](http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox). I'm not sure if it makes a difference but my host is ArchLinux with Intel Haswell with Iris Pro Graphics.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. not sure if this is right or not. I did this, and it fixed something:

from http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html

> You need to change the CPUID to a non-Haswell ID to fix the issue
>   non-booting 10.8 on a Haswell CPU:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm {your vm name here} –cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 02100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
```

But I'm having some trouble remembering the exact chain of events. It might've been another tweak later on that got XCode to install properly.

Regardless, I feel dirty for even attempting to do this.  I hoped I would never be put in a situation where I had to cheat on Linux, but it beats spending over a grand (despite that mine is top-notch) to work on a useless iPhone app.  In other words, it sucks being an independent commodity producer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error, but on actual Apple hardware.
Despite that, the display link object does seem to work.

Maybe it's because it is not familiar with my Dell monitor.